# Symplectic forms and 1-forms

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, cotangent-bundles

Suppose we have a real symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$. Under what conditions can we find a global 1-form $\alpha$ such that $\omega = \alpha \wedge\alpha$?
Obviously there are some simple obstructions, for example, the cotangent bundle must admit a non-vanishing section (thus, surfaces of genus $>1$ are out). However it does not seem easy to come up with sufficient conditions.

Comment: For a one-form $\alpha$, $\alpha \wedge \alpha = 0$.

Comment: And then you should do an immediate excercise.  If ω=α∧β then then M is...

Comment: Do you want to have $w=d \alpha$?

Comment: $\dim M = 0   $

Comment: This question was incredibly badly phrased, for which I apologize. I meant to ask in the case where we tensor the exterior algebra with something nonabelian.
But even then as Gal pointed out the answer is easy.

Answer (score 5):

You can never find such a $1$-form since any $1$-form wedge itself is identically zero.